# DLNA Windows 7 Networking Wireless, Wired

Tags: windows-7, dlna

My Configuration is Windows 7 Ultimate. I've got a Nokia Seimens Wireless router/modem which connects to the SONY Bravia TV (EX520) and my laptop connects to the wireless.. I've also got a computer which connects to the router via a wired connection . The problem is when i try to stream media from my laptop to the tv via DLNA. It just doesnt work. 
Windows 7 doesn't detect the TV in the media devices under the Network. But i can ping the IP of the TV and it responds correctly. 
DLNA streaming from the Wired Computer responds perfectly .
Btw i'm using TVersity Pro.

I've set the IP of the TV to static > 192.168.1.4

Router/Modem is at > 192.168.1.1

The Laptop connects to > 192.168.1.2

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: If you hook the problematic notebook up via a wire, does it work then?  Does your router support uPnP (what DNLA uses to discover devices) over wireless?   Has it been enabled?

Comment: yes it works with a wire.. I can't find an enable uPnP option anywhere on my router.. Its a Nokia Seimens Residential Router 1600 .